# How to stop overlapping paths cutting fill colour out

Tags: adobe-photoshop, path

I have the following issue whereby I wanted to draw a tree with overlapping paths (so I could edit individual branches in the future) but when I overlap the path, it cuts the fill out:

[image]

How do you stop this? so that the white path tree fills regardless of overlapping paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, this is all one path. You need to be making multiple paths for each branch or when you get to a branch, change direction and drawl the new branch. This will solve your issue.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a more scalable way of doing this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by scalable. If I were to make a tree with the pen tool, I would use Illustrator.

Comment: I meant that if I divide the path up, I then have to solve the problem of having layer masks on different paths... and having to set the colour on every new branch that overlaps another... and I guess if I make more branches (scalable) it might get rather annoying although i'm aware of copy style... Right, I better get illustrator then... Thanks bro! Helpful to know you definitely can't do it in Photoshop. I just tried because I have only purchased the sub to that so far...